# Inserting values automatically in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have the following stored procedure to insert purchasing of vouchers, but only recieving the USer_ID which is a foreign key in my Voucher table, but the other fields are entered automatically, here is my stored procedure`

```
create proc InsertPurchaseVouchers
    (
       @User_ID int = null,
       @Amount decimal(18,2)

    )
    As

    Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
      IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                        FROM    Voucher
                        WHERE   [User_Id] = @User_ID)
                    Insert into Voucher
                    (
                      Voucher_Id,
                      Voucher_Amount,
                      Voucher_ExpirityDate,
                      Voucher__PurchaseDate,
                      [User_Id]
                    )
                    values(
                               1,
                               @Amount,
                               DateAdd(m,3,GetDate()),
                               GetDate(),
                               @User_ID
                          )
                          set Voucher_Id  = Scope_Identity

    End`
```

and my tables

```
 USE [CSIS3714_MakaringiH]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Voucher]    Script Date: 2015/05/14 11:11:09 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Voucher](
    [Voucher_Id] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Voucher_Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Voucher_ExpirityDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Voucher__PurchaseDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [User_Id] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Voucher_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Voucher]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_Voucher_User] FOREIGN KEY([User_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([User_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Voucher] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_Voucher_User]
GO

    USE [CSIS3714_MakaringiH]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 2015/05/14 11:12:14 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [User_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [User_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_Password] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [User_CellNumber] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [User_IsActive] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [UserRole_Id] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [User_FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_Surnamr] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_IdNumber] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [User_AirTimeBalance] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [User_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_User_Role] FOREIGN KEY([UserRole_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UserRole] ([UserRole_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_User_Role]
GO
```

The voucher expires in 3 months

Comment: and what exactly is your question?

Comment: point of correcting the stored procedure should recieve the amount as well

Comment: How do i get the other values that are not entered when executing the stored procedures

Comment: Please edit your question to include your comments. Also, replace the mysqli tag with the tag that specifies your sql server version.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it seems you are wanting to populate Voucher_ID automatically.  Your best bet is to add IDENTITY property to Voucher_ID column. That will auto generate a value in that column when you do an insert.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Voucher](
[Voucher_Id] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY, -- change to bigint datatype, mark IDENTITY
[Voucher_Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[Voucher_ExpirityDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Voucher__PurchaseDate] [datetime] NULL,
[User_Id] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Voucher_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Your INSERT statement will now exclude the the VOUCHER_ID column:

```
INSERT dbo.Voucher (Voucher_Amount, Voucher_ExpirityDate, Voucher__PurchaseDate, User_Id)
VALUES (@Amount, DateAdd(m,3,GetDate()), GetDate(), @User_ID)
```